# How to search with name and number in jquery autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I need to search with name or number in jquery autocomplete

i tried this:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="plugins" name="plugins" />
```

script:

```
var arraY = [{name: "xxx", phone_number: "9997515744},{name: "abc", phone_number: "9619054073"},{name: "asd", phone_number: "9323135708"}]
$("#plugins").autocomplete({source: plugin_names});
```

from above array i need to search with both name and phone_number , but now only phone number search is working,name search is not working.

Anyone help me .

Comment: Can you try with my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

autocomplete takes callback function as the `source` which has the below arguments

A `request` object, with a single term property, which refers to the value currently in the text input.

A `response` callback, which expects a single argument: the data to suggest to the user. This data should be filtered based on the provided term, and can be in any of the formats described above for simple local data.

check out this link 
http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source

Can you try with the below code

```js
var arraY = [{name: "xxx", phone_number: "9997515744"},{name: "abc", phone_number: "9619054073"},{name: "asd", phone_number: "9323135708"}];

// the typed data is in request.term

function multipleFieldMatch(request, response) {
    function isMatch(s) {
        return s.toLowerCase().indexOf(request.term.toLowerCase())!==-1;
    }
    var i, len, obj, totalMatches = [];
    len = arraY.length;

    if (request.term==="") {
        response([]);
        return;
    }

    for  (i = 0; i<len; i++) {
        obj = arraY[i];
        if (isMatch(obj.name) || isMatch(obj.phone_number))    {
            totalMatches.push(obj);
        }
    }
    response(totalMatches);
}

$( "#plugins").autocomplete({
    source: multipleFieldMatch
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="plugins" name="plugins" />
```

Comment: Just an FYI, `request.term` will never be `""` unless `minLength` is set to 0. The default for `minLength` is 1.

Comment: Also, if number of lines is important, you can swap out `for` loop for jQuery `$.each()`.

Comment: Yeah you are correct about the minlength part, I just added the check as a default

Comment: hey its working fine , but i need to display both name and phone number in the dropdown , if the name is empty need to show un named , i will try to workout it , if u have any idea means kindly share .

Answer (score 1):

You should probably try using the ajax option and make the search on the server side

```
$('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
    serviceUrl: '/autocomplete/countries',
    onSelect: function (suggestion) {
        alert('You selected: ' + suggestion.value + ', ' + suggestion.data);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

From the API Documentation, I would suggest using `source` as a callback function.

> **Function:** The third variation, a callback, provides the most flexibility and can be used to connect any data source to Autocomplete, including JSONP. The callback gets two arguments:
>
> A `request` object, with a single `term` property, which refers to the value currently in the text input. For example, if the user enters `"new yo"` in a city field, the Autocomplete term will equal `"new yo"`.
>
> A `response` callback, which expects a single argument: the data to suggest to the user. This data should be filtered based on the provided term, and can be in any of the formats described above for simple local data. It's important when providing a custom source callback to handle errors during the request. You must always call the `response` callback even if you encounter an error. This ensures that the widget always has the correct state.

Also, your source array needs to contain a `label` and `value`, it can have more data, yet these two are a must. See more about Custom Data: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data

I would advise something like:

**JavaScript**

```
var myData = [{
  label: "xxx",
  value: "9997515744"
}, {
  label: "abc",
  value: "9619054073"
}, {
  label: "asd",
  value: "9323135708"
}];
$(function() {
  $("#plugins").autocomplete({
    source: function(req, resp) {
      var results = [];
      $.each(myData, function(k, v) {
        // Make a pass for names
        if (v.label.indexOf(req.term) != -1) {
          results.push(v);
          return;
        }
        // Make a pass for phone
        if (v.value.indexOf(req.term) != -1) {
          results.push(v);
          return;
        }
      });
      resp(results);
    }
  });
});
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/urtkxo46/

Comment: Label and value are only required if you are using the out of the box search by autocomplete as it looks for a label to display and a value to be selected in behind in the onselect event. For custom callback you can use any property provided you are handling the Search

Comment: hey its working fine , but i need to display both name and phone number in the dropdown , if the name is empty need to show un named , i will try to workout it , if u have any idea means kindly share .

Comment: Look at the custom data link I included.  Should be able to work something out from that. Otherwise post a new question. If this answer helped you, consider marking it as the answer.